# How do I catch an Ajax query post error?

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, error-handling

I would like to catch the error and show the appropriate message if the Ajax request fails.

My code is like the following, but I could not manage to catch the failing Ajax request.

```
function getAjaxData(id)
{
     $.post("status.ajax.php", {deviceId : id}, function(data){

        var tab1;

        if (data.length>0) {
            tab1 = data;
        }
        else {
            tab1 = "Error in Ajax";
        }

        return tab1;
    });
}
```

I found out that, "Error in Ajax" is never executed when the Ajax request failed.

How do I handle the Ajax error and show the appropriate message if it fails?

Answer (score 368, accepted):

Since jQuery 1.5 you can use the deferred objects mechanism:

```
$.post('some.php', {name: 'John'})
    .done(function(msg){  })
    .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
        // error handling
    });
```

Another way is using `.ajax`:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: "name=John&location=Boston",
  success: function(msg){
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  },
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     alert("some error");
  }
});
```

Comment: @Yuck $.post can accept an error callback using deferred objects. Take a look at my answer below for an example.

Comment: Also, I way to make `$.ajax` more readable is to use a hash for your `data`. For example: `{ name : 'John', location: 'Boston' }`

Comment: The success and error callbacks above are obsolete as of jQuery 1.8 http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: @MichaelVeneble i think you can use `$.post().error()`

Answer (score 310):

jQuery 1.5 added deferred objects that handle this nicely. Simply call `$.post` and attach any handlers you'd like after the call. Deferred objects even allow you to attach multiple success and error handlers.

Example:

```
$.post('status.ajax.php', {deviceId: id})
    .done( function(msg) { ... } )
    .fail( function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    });
```

Prior to jQuery 1.8, the function `done` was called `success` and `fail` was called `error`.

Comment: +1 Very nice, but still not crazy about the syntax.  Hopefully it gets unified in a future release.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The current accepted answer is "use a different method"; this answer says "here's how to make your method work". The latter is usually preferred on SO. Actually, this should be included in the $.post documentation!!!

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail , http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done for documentation

Comment: By the way there is also `responseJSON` property which is also very handy in case of ajax type is `json`.

Comment: `xhr.responseText` appears to be the needle in the fail-callback haystack. But I would suggest adding `dataType: 'text'` to the 2nd parameter to $.post. That [might](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Ajax/#data-types) help direct an error message of a different content-type to show up in responseText. But I haven't checked.

Answer (score 99):

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'status.ajax.php',
  data: {
     deviceId: id
  },
  success: function(data){
     // your code from above
  },
  error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){
      console.log(xhr.statusText);
      console.log(textStatus);
      console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 18):

```
$.post('someUri', { }, 
  function(data){ doSomeStuff })
 .fail(function(error) { alert(error.responseJSON) });
```

Comment: Adding a bit more explanation here would help future readers.

Answer (score 14):

A simple way is to implement [ajaxError](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/):

> Whenever an Ajax request completes
>   with an error, jQuery triggers the
>   ajaxError event. Any and all handlers
>   that have been registered with the
>   .ajaxError() method are executed at
>   this time.

For example:

```
$('.log').ajaxError(function() {
  $(this).text('Triggered ajaxError handler.');
});
```

I would suggest reading the [ajaxError](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/) documentation. It does more than the simple use-case demonstrated above - mainly its callback accepts a number of parameters:

```
$('.log').ajaxError(function(e, xhr, settings, exception) {
  if (settings.url == 'ajax/missing.html') {
    $(this).text('Triggered ajaxError handler.');
  }
});
```

Comment: +1 - I would add that this handler gets several arguments, so you can display the actual error, response code, url, etc.

Comment: Note that as of jQuery 1.8, the .ajaxError() method should only be attached to document.

Answer (score 3):

You have to log the responseText:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'status.ajax.php',
    data: {
    deviceId: id
  }
})
.done(
 function (data) {
  //your code
 }
)
.fail(function (data) {
      console.log( "Ajax failed: " + data['responseText'] );
})
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to utilize .then() [which has a subtle difference in comparison with .done()](https://makandracards.com/makandra/39543-jquery-promises-done-and-then-are-not-the-same) :

```
return $.post(url, payload)
.then(
    function (result, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        return result;
    },
    function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        return console.error(errorThrown);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you attach the .onerror handler to the ajax object, why people insist on posting JQuery for responses when vanila works cross platform...

quickie example:

```
ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open( "POST", "/url/to/handler.php", true );
ajax.onerror = function(){
    alert("Oops! Something went wrong...");
}
ajax.send(someWebFormToken );
```

Comment: can't resist to try and answer the why : easier to read and debug, faster to implement, especially if you have lots of parameters, there are plenty of tools to generate beatiful $.ajax statement with their parameters

Comment: Using a library all the time exposes you to any underlying bugs, exploits and you are reliant on the library and not raw code which IMHO is always a better option. Learn to code not to use a library, there is no rapid development with a library, that is a popular myth.