# jQuery.post doesn't return any response

Tags: jquery

I *POST* the values to my server using jQuery (API call). The values are succesfully added to the db
but I don't get any response from the server.

Here is my jquery for post .

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#signupConfirm').click(function () {
        if (validateSignUpForm()) {
            //check the availability of username.

            // post all these vars into the API call
            var signUpServiceUrl = 'http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
            var apiKey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
            var apiSecret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
            var userName = $('#username').val();
            var email = $('#email1').val();
            var password = $('#password1').val();

            $.post(signUpServiceUrl, {
                    'api_key': apiKey,
                    'api_secret': apiSecret,
                    'username': userName,
                    'email': email,
                    'password': password
            }, function (data) {
                result = JSON.parse(data);
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Is there any mistake in this?

Comment: grab the error using this and debug further http://stackoverflow.com/a/2833968/953684

Comment: check browser dev tools console for errors. Also check network section to watch server request/response values.

Comment: After doing the above ^ please show an example of the returned JSON. Are you sure it's valid? Is this a cross-domain request? What are you doing with result and why is it global?

Comment: @spokey this is the sample respone that i expect {"header":{"status":"200","status_text":"OK"},"data":{"id_user":"38"}}

Comment: @spokey this will not get in the jquery.

Comment: It will go in `result`, are you sure it's not there? Any console error messages?

Comment: what are you sending in response?

Comment: @Spokey The console says this .. Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.                                                 ,           fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net : server does not support RFC 5746, see CVE-2009-3555                . As a new person i don't understand what it is. will u please explain.

Comment: @Apul Gupta.   I send the response like this.  {"header":{"status":"200","status_text":"OK"},"data":{"id_user":"38"}}

Comment: You are sending request to another domain or sub-domain, that's why getting cross-origin request error. right?

Comment: Yes, you are not allowed to send requests like this to another domain. Try putting jsonp at the end of post like this and try again `function (data) { alert(data) }, 'jsonp');` if you do this there is no need to parse again, probably

Comment: @Spokey i added 'jsonp' at the end of the post but it will return an empty alert box..   $.post(signUpServiceUrl,{'api_key':apiKey,'api_secret':apiSecret,'username':userName,'email':email,'password':password},function(data){ alert(data),'jsonp';
   });

Comment: open your browser console and at the network tab look at the headers when you are sending it. See what you get if you go to that page. The request now reaches the server, you now have to debug it. See the sent data if it's right or not.

Comment: it give the status code for OK (200). But the response tab here is empty..

Answer (score 0):

You are sending cross-domain requests, use `jsonp`. Here is an example:

http://hayageek.com/cross-domain-ajax-request-jquery/

Comment: i added jsonp at the end of the post but it will not return any thing... Alert box returns only blank.

Comment: I have not suggested to use `jsonp` in the end of `$.post`. Try the example given in answer.  http://hayageek.com/cross-domain-ajax-request-jquery/