# jQuery $.post not sending form data...?

Tags: jquery

I have this jQuery code:

```
var strURL = "svcs/mapHelper.aspx";
var strPost = "action=add&mapId=<%= getCurrentMapId() %>&coordX=" + fltX + "&coordY=" + fltY + "&coordName=" + strCoordName + "&ipRanges=" + strIPRanges;

$.post(strURL, strPost, function(data) {
    strResponse = data;
    console.log(strResponse);
    if (data == 'Added') {
        //$('#postResult').text(strResponse);
        $('#inp_coordName').val('');
        $('#spn_addIPwarnings').val('');
        $('#addCoordinate').dialog('close');
        location.reload();
    } else {
        $('#spn_addIPwarnings').text('Error when adding region');
    }
});
```

and it works fine on most browsers, but I have a client, using chrome, and it appears that the form data in strPost doesn't post, I don't see it in the network Form Data in the chrome debug window...
What can it be ???

Comment: Try adding an error section after the method.    `,error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     alert(XMLHttpRequest.textStatus);
  }`  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2833968/1888402

Output the error and see if it helps you.

Comment: because of it `location.reload();`.

Comment: I tried adding .fail() but it didn't get to that code block...

Comment: Why the location.reload() ?