# What is the correct way to return a specialized HTTP response?

Tags: rest, http, httpresponse

Let's say that in my RESTful interface I require the client to include some special header, just to indicate it's an authorized client. (Trust me on this; it's a requirement of the project.) If the HTTP request contains an incorrect value in this header, the server needs to send back an HTTP response that the client can recognize that it sent an unsupported value in the header.

What's the appropriate way to send back this information using HTTP?

- I could send back a `400 Bad Request` response, but how do I tell the client what the problem was exactly? The obvious option is to include some message in the body of the response. But (besides issues of i18n) is it really a good idea for the client to blindly display the contents of an error message?
- I could send back a `400 Bad Request` response, with a proprietary special header indicating that such-and-such header had the wrong code. This has the benefit that the client can actually process what the error was (as opposed to free text in the content). So does the `400` response then become a catch-all response, with the actual error in some proprietary header? Is this a good general pattern? But that almost suggests...
- I could could send back some arbitrary `4XX` response that has a proprietary meaning, such as `472 Bad Foo Header Value`. Microsoft seems to have gone this route at times. The obvious problem is the possibility of clashes in a future version of HTTP (or with others who have done the same thing).

I suppose I'm leaning more toward `400 Bad Request` with a special header indicating the error specialization. Any thoughts or experience with this use case?

Comment: "Guidance" == "maybe doesn't belong on [so]".

Comment: Puleaze. If you don't like the word "guidance", I'll change it to "what is the best way to return a custom HTTP response"? Look at the semantics of the entire sentence, please.

Comment: I meant the fact that you're seeking guidance instead of asking a specific programming question. [so] is not the place for guidance. I could as easily have voted to close this as "Primarily opinion-based", since you're "leaning" and since you're looking for "thoughts or experience".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the special header is incorrectly formatted then you could send a
400 Bad request Response indicating that the header is wrong.

However If the sole purpose of the header is authorization and you reject the header, because of invalid value, then I would opt for:

1. 403 - Forbidden, if you want the connection to be refused
2. 401 - Unauthorized, if the client should try to reauthenticate

In the Response phrase you can indicate the reason for refusing the connection.

Comment: Yeah, but if it's an authentication or authorization header, then don't be too specific about the reasons! Just "not authorized" is good enough.

Comment: The problem is that, if we send back `401` or `403`, the client will then try to re-authenticate and pop up a dialog asking for the user's credentials again. I suppose we could add a special header indicating that the exact reason for being forbidden so that the client can distinguish between that and an authentication problem, but then we could do the same thing with `400`.

Comment: Is it a Javascript client? Then an ajax post request, with error handling would do the trick. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833951/how-to-catch-ajax-query-post-error

Comment: It could be any type of client.

Comment: I think you are correct in that semantically the appropriate response in this situation is `403 Forbidden`. While it's certainly appropriate to indicate the reason in the response phrase (in the body of the response), this is not easily machine processable, so in my implementation I additionally send back a special, proprietary header, allowing the client to distinguish between this special case and other `403 Forbidden` situations.