# Asp.Net MVC 4, Form submit not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a simple Asp.Net MVC 4 Chat application. 
Below the chat session is initialized, I ask the user to enter the name and once the user enters his name (and other details not shown in below code) and presses on the `"Start Chat"` button, the Action method `ChatForm` is called from the `Chat` controller.

Code snippet for the chat form is as shown below:

```
@model WebSite.ViewModel.SimpleForm

using (Html.BeginForm("ChatForm", "Chat", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "anonymousChat" }))
{
<div class='form-group'>
    @Html.LabelRequiredFor(m => m.Name)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
<input type="submit" class='btn btn-block start-anonymous-chat' value="Start Chat" />
}
```

The `ChatForm` method is as shown below:

```
public ActionResult ChatForm(SimpleForm model)
{
      /*Some processing is done here and finally the below values are returned*/

      return Json(new { success = true, chatId=chatRequest.Id, compId=company.Id });
}
```

Now the problem is after executing this function, i get the below line on the browser:

```
{"success":true,"chatId":10734,"compId":109}
```

The method executed on click of the submit button is:

```
$("#anonymousChat").submit(function () {
            debugger;
            if ($("#anonymousChat").valid())
                $.ajax({
                    type: this.method,
                    url: this.action,
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    success: function (data) {

                        if (data.success) {
                            /*show the chat modal*/
                            chatModal.modal("show");

                        }
                        else {
                            console.log("failed");
                            $("#anon-chat-form").html(data);
                        }
                    }
                });

            return false;
        });
```

Also if i try to put any alert message or console messages within the method `$("#anonymousChat").submit`, then neither the alter is popped-up nor the console messages or being printed.

Has anyone been hit by similar problem before? Is so how did you solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: its obvious that your call is not entering in the success method. update the ajax call by adding error method then you can catch the error

Comment: @Optimus: error method??

Comment: check this link its shows how to trace ajax error.. .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833951/how-to-catch-ajax-query-post-error

Comment: @Optimus, What has the (obsolete) `Ajax.BeginForm()` method got to do with _pure MVC_?

Comment: try using this function instead of your submit `$(document).on('submit', '#anonymousChat', function (e) {});`

Comment: @StephenMuecke My mistake I forgot that...

Answer (score 1):

The alert is not showing up, so the submit event is not triggered.

If your form is dynamically added to the DOM then the `$("#anonymousChat").submit(function () {}` won't trigger anything because the form does not exist yet when the page loads.
Try changing your code like this to avoid this problem:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#anonymousChat', function (e) {
  debugger;
        if ($("#anonymousChat").valid())
            $.ajax({
                type: this.method,
                url: this.action,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data) {

                    if (data.success) {
                        /*show the chat modal*/
                        chatModal.modal("show");

                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("failed");
                        $("#anon-chat-form").html(data);
                    }
                }
            });

        return false;
});
```

If it stil does not work maybe your problem is much simpler than that, maybe you just didn't reference the javascript file.

Answer (score 0):

your form ID is "myChat" however you're referencing "anonymousChat" in your JavaScript, believe this might be causing your issues