# Sending request to domain using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

i wanted to know that can we send a request using ajax.like can we use domain name with file in URL property of ajax? if no then what to use instead of this ?

```
$.ajax({
    url:'http://www.domain.com/myfile.php',
})
```

thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the url can be a full url or a relative one.

[`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) documentation has some examples of that.

Comment: $.ajax({

      url:'http://domain.com/data.php',
      type:'post',
      
      success:function(msg){
       alert(msg)
      }
     })

i used this and nothing happened .. it should show a alert with ok

Comment: you have a ';' after the domain url. Try removing it. Also try this:

Comment: did but same .. no progress
$.ajax({

      url:'http://domain.com/data.php',
      type:'post',

      success:function(msg){
       alert(msg)
      }
     })

Comment: You still have the ';,' sequence after ''domain.com/data.php'. You only need the ','.

Comment: i dont know why its showing here in comment .. its ',' in the code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131300/discussion-between-hicaro-and-adeel-pervaiz).

Comment: i attached the picture in post .. please check that

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to use the code below (taken from [this repose](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2833968/829132))
2. Verify console in your browser dev tools (press F12 in chrome), probably there is an error

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://www.domain.com/myfile.php",
  success: function(msg){
      alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  },
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert("some error");
  }
});
```

Comment: $.ajax({

      url:'http://domain.com/data.php',
      type:'post',
      
      success:function(msg){
       alert(msg)
      }
     })

i used this and nothing happened .. it should show a alert with ok