# Jquery Post is not passing data to url Using Codeigniter framework

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, .post

This is my first time to experience this. I have a jquery script that submit form data to the server(PHP). This script work perfectly while I was using another template but on switching to another template the script stop working correctly. In my effort to know what exactly is wrong I noticed that the $.post is not sending any data to the url.

```
        <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#addvotemate").click(function() {
    var vuniq_userid = $("#vuniq_userid").val();
    var vmuniq_userid = $("#vmuniq_userid").val();
   //alert("I work to this point");
    if (vuniq_userid == '' || vmuniq_userid == '' ) {
   alert("Request Failed Try Again");
    } else {
   // alert(vuniq_userid +' '+ vmuniq_userid);

     $.post("<?php echo site_url('user/addvotemate'); ?>", {
       vuniq_userid1: vuniq_userid,
       vmuniq_userid1: vmuniq_userid


      }, function() {
     alert("Message Sent");


      $('#votreq')[0].reset(); // To reset form fields

    });
    }
    });
   });
   </script>
```

Am using Codeigniter 3X, Template bootstrap 3, jquery.1.11.1.min.js
 View:

```
      <div id="votm">
                    <form id="votreq" name="form" method="POST">

                        <input type="hidden" id="vuniq_userid" 
        name="vuniq_userid" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['uniqueID'] ?>">
                        <input type="hidden" id="vmuniq_userid" 
    name="vmuniq_userid" value="<?php echo $pid ?>" >

                        <btn class="btn btn-sm btn-azure btn-icon" 
   id="addvotemate"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-users"></i> Add Votemate</btn>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

I need your kind help as I don't even understand how to solve the problem. I have tried different approach but still no luck. I have use jsfidle. Thanks

Comment: Can you please try to capture the error or use an alternative to $.post shown below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2833968/3254405

Comment: There is no error message. But if there is a way to do that, kindly put me through.

Comment: Can you use your browser's developer's tool to see what, if any, URL `$post()` is calling?

Comment: Yes, I think it does. I have these: "http://[::1]/votemate/index.php/user/addvotemate"

Comment: The `[::1]votemate/` part tells me you have not set a value for `$config['base_url']`

Comment: @DFriend       Thanks, I have done that now like this:$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/votemate/'; 
 So I check and saw this:  http://localhost/votemate/user/addvotemate

Comment: @DFriend       The problem not solved yet.

Comment: The value should include the protocol, i.e. `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/';` If you have given you virtual host a server name then use that instead of `localhost`.

Comment: @DFriend       That's exactly what I did. Is stackoverflow that is stripping the http off here.

Comment: You should be using the codeigniter form method. Form_open(user/addvotemate, $args)

Comment: @Brad          I am trying to prevent the whole page refresh and make it as dynamic as possible. The only way to get that done is by using Ajax.

Comment: using the codeigniter form is just how you structure the form not use ajax. It is much more secure. The $args is an array of your form ID that triggers ajax

Comment: @Brad          Ok, can you show me an examle of how to use $args

Comment: I will put it in the answer box, but you dont have to treat it as an answer

Comment: @DFriend        I noticed this is being added automatically to my form. Hoping this could be the reason for the problem. Do I have to create a row for it in my database?<input type="hidden" name="csrf_test_name" value="cc0294deffcc52f34bcdbcxxxxxxxxx" />

Comment: Not sure it's your problem. If it is then the response from the ajax call will be a 403 Not allowed error. The field is the CSRF protection field and the value will be stripped from `$_POST` data before it gets to the controller. So, no you do not need to store it in your database. Read about [CSRF here.](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf)

Comment: @DFriend        No, I did not store it in my database but I include it in my Ajax script since its an input with value and it worked. You are very correct. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using codeigniter forms

```
$args = [
'id' => 'votreq',
'name' => 'form',
];
echo form_open('user/addvotemate', $args);
```

This replaces:

```
<form id="votreq" name="form" method="POST">
```

This automatically escapes your form inputs. Much more secure. Please use the codeigniter manual, its very helpful.

Comment: Before anyone down votes this as not being an answer, this is here merely to show the op how to use codeigniter form open

Comment: I have replaced the form tag with the code you posted but not yet solved the problem. How to relate it to the Ajax script?

Comment: I noticed this is being added automatically to my form. Hoping this could be the reason for the problem. Do I have to create a row for it in my database?<input type="hidden" name="csrf_test_name" value="cc0294deffcc52f34bcdbc12xxxxxxx" />

Comment: Your suggestion lead me to the solution. I have finally figured it out. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Sholley, The ID = votreq is what you use to trigger the ajax script

Answer (score 0):

This is how I figured it out.
Simply because am using the codeigniter CSRF Security feature, an hidden input field is being added to my form:

```
    <input type="hidden" name="csrf_test_name" 
     value="cc0294deffcc52f34bcdbcxxxxxxxxx" />
```

I detected this through the developer tool of firefox browser debugger.
The following is my initial script which does not include the csrf hidden field:

```
     <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#addvotemate").click(function() {
      var vuniq_userid = $("#vuniq_userid").val();
     var vmuniq_userid = $("#vmuniq_userid").val();
    //alert("I work to this point");
    if (vuniq_userid == '' || vmuniq_userid == '' ) {
    alert("Request Failed Try Again");
     } else {
   // alert(vuniq_userid +' '+ vmuniq_userid);

 $.post("<?php echo site_url('user/addvotemate'); ?>", {
   vuniq_userid1: vuniq_userid,
   vmuniq_userid1: vmuniq_userid


  }, function() {
 alert("Message Sent");


  $('#votreq')[0].reset(); // To reset form fields

  });
    }
    });
    });
  </script>
```

So, I decided to include the hidden field in my script like this:

```
      <script>
       $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#addvotemate").click(function(e) {

       e.preventDefault();
       var csrf = $('[name="csrf_test_name"]').val();    
        var vuniq_userid = $("#vuniq_userid").val();
       var vmuniq_userid = $("#vmuniq_userid").val();

           if (vuniq_userid == '' || vmuniq_userid == '' ) {
           alert("Request Failed Try Again");
          } else {

         $.post("<?php echo site_url('user/addvotemate'); ?>", {
        csrf_test_name: csrf,
         vuniq_userid1: vuniq_userid,
        vmuniq_userid1: vmuniq_userid

            }, function() {
           alert("Message Sent");


            $('#votreq')[0].reset(); // To reset form fields

         });
            }
       });
      });
     </script>
```

After I did that my Ajax script begins to work properly.